# Building in different linux-based OS

Tags: ubuntu, build, cmake, fedora, qmake

I'm not experienced in C, qt and cmake.

I spent last 10 hours trying to build this project:
https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-qt

May main goal is to build it myself and run it on Ubuntu.

README describes that in order to build I need to install all those libraries:

```
openssl-devel qt5-devel SDL2-devel ffmpeg-devel qt5-qtquickcontrols2-devel libva-devel libvdpau-devel opus-devel pulseaudio-libs-devel alsa-lib-devel SDL2_ttf-devel
```

I'm trying to build it on Ubuntu, but I found out, that those libraries cannot be installed by simple "apt" command. I installed the newest Fedora, then using yum I installed libs and built project successfully.

After that, I copied binaries to my Ubuntu system, but I couldn't run it. A lot of shared libraries are missing on my Ubuntu. Also qt version of my Ubuntu is older than used to build on Fedora.

Compiled version downloaded from github "releases" tab for Ubuntu works well.

Because I don't know exactly how to solve my problem, I have 3 questions:

1. Do it makes sense to build under Fedora and run under Ubuntu?
2. Can I somehow force "make" command to include all those shared
   libraries and qt-related libraries to project?
3. If not, maybe I can install yum on Ubuntu and then I could easily install recommended libs?

Comment: Better ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: If is better to install required libraries on Ubuntu, build the project their and use it. Most of those libraries should be available on Ubuntu via its package manager. If you cannot find some package on Ubuntu, ask about this specific package. And yes, Stack Overflow is not suitable place for questions about installing the packages via the package manager.

Comment: How is **CMake** related with the problem? Note, this is neither a `qmake`, which is used for configure your project, nor a `make`, which is used for build it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the equivalent libraries for Ubuntu.  Those dependencies work for RHEL flavored Linuxes (like Fedora, CentOS, and RedHat).  For example:

```
RHEL package   Ubuntu package

openssl-devel  libssl-dev
ffmpeg-devel   libavcodec-dev
qt5-devel      qtdeclarative5-dev
opus-devel     libopus-dev
```

Just search for "*PACKAGE_NAME* in Ubuntu" to find the equivalent package names.

#### References

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libopus-dev
- https://serverfault.com/questions/249340/install-openssl-dev-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: That answer is nice.. but it should be on the *other site*, not on the Stack Overflow. Why do you ever answer a definitely **off-topic**  question?

Comment: This is what I were trying to do at the beginning, but (for example) even after installing libssl-dev, cmake didn't see this library.


@Tsyvarev - Why this is off-topic? Can't ask questions related with building and libraries here?

Comment: "Can't ask questions related with building and libraries here?" - You can. But currently your question is about searching libraries via package manager. "even after installing libssl-dev, cmake didn't see this library." - Please, **be specific** when describe the problem. What **exactly** is printed by qmake? On Ubuntu 16 [libssl-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libssl-dev/filelist) provides `openssl.pc` file, so `pkgconfig` utility, used by qmake, should find that library.